Facing this issue while running Test cases through TestNG
I have installed my testNG from the marketplace. I am studying software testing using Selenium with Java. I expect a print out with this basic code, instead, it displays an error.
package TestNGAnnotation;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void sampletest1() {

        System.out.println("this is testNG annotation ");
    }
}

Following is the error. I did not see error in my script or the library. Is there anything I am missing?
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.10.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.lambda$getLogger$0(Logger.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:30)
    at org.testng.TestNG.<clinit>(TestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNGFactory7_9.createRemoteTestNG(RemoteTestNGFactory7_9.java:16)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 6 more


Seems you missed the dependency "slf4j"
Check your build file. make sure the slf4j is configured in your build file.
you can get the version and configuration example from SLF4J API Module
